# How to make polling on react-table

Tags: reactjs, polling, react-table

I'm trying to build a React-Table which can make polling to a remote server every second to fetch newest data. I just followed what the author did in the doc (https://react-table.js.org/#/story/server-side-data) and tried integrate the polling function (setInterval) in "componentDidMount" but it FAILED.

The error message shows that when running "requestData" under "componentDidMount", "filtered" is undefined, whose length is not accessible. How can I fix that? Thank you.

```js
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash'

import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css'


const requestData = (pageSize, page, sorted, filtered) => {
    return fetch(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/agent',
        { method: 'GET'}
    ).then( res => res.json()
    ).then( filteredData => {

        if (filtered.length) {
            filteredData = filtered.reduce((filteredSoFar, nextFilter) => {
                return filteredSoFar.filter(row => {
                    return (row[nextFilter.id] + "").includes(nextFilter.value);
                });
            }, filteredData);
        }

        const sortedData = _.orderBy(
            filteredData,
            sorted.map(sort => {
                return row => {
                    if (row[sort.id] === null || row[sort.id] === undefined) {
                        return -Infinity;
                    }
                    return typeof row[sort.id] === "string"
                        ? row[sort.id].toLowerCase()
                        : row[sort.id];
                };
            }),
            sorted.map(d => (d.desc ? "desc" : "asc"))
        );

        const res = {
            rows: sortedData.slice(pageSize * page, pageSize * page + pageSize),
            pages: Math.ceil(filteredData.length / pageSize)
        };

        return res;
    });
};


class AgentTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            pages: null,
//            loading: true,
        };
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData(state, instance) {
//        this.setState({
//            loading: true
//        });
        requestData(
            state.pageSize,
            state.page,
            state.sorted,
            state.filtered
        ).then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.rows,
                pages: res.pages,
//                loading: false,
            })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(
            () => requestData(
                this.state.pageSize,
                this.state.page,
                this.state.sorted,
                this.state.filtered
            ).then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.rows,
                    pages: res.pages,
//                    loading: false,
                })
            }), 5000
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { data, pages, loading } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    columns={[
                        {
                            Header: "Agent ID",
                            accessor: "AGENTID"
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Description",
                            accessor: "DESCRIPTION"
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Domain",
                            accessor: "DOMAIN"
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Register Time",
                            accessor: "REGTIME"
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Status",
                            accessor: "STATUS"
                        },
                    ]}
                    manual // Forces table not to paginate or sort automatically, so we can handle it server-side
                    data={data}
                    pages={pages} // Display the total number of pages
                    loading={loading} // Display the loading overlay when we need it
                    onFetchData={this.fetchData} // Request new data when things change
                    filterable
                    defaultPageSize={20}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AgentTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to understand what the `onFetchData` callback is.
Taken from the docs, `onFetchData` is:

`This function is called at componentDidMount and any time sorting, pagination or filterting is changed in the table`

So what you're trying to achieve here won't work the way tried to. 
Seeing as fetching data from a remote server every second isn't one of the conditions that invoke the `onFetchData` callback, you should try a different approach.

I forked `React-Table`'s `Simple Table` example and added timed data requests [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0pq6wyq1r), this should help you get started.